# SDL window crashing after appearing?

Tags: c++, window, sdl-2

My SDL window is not staying up: it almost immediately closes upon opening, with the Visual Studio Debug Console staying open:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLwindow", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
   
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to increase the delay but apart from that I am not sure what I am meant to fix.

Comment: This is to be expected with such code. You need a main loop loop, which will continuously redraw everything, and will also contain the event loop (`while (SDL_PollEvent(...))`). Your tutorial should explain this, probably in the next chapter or something like this.

Comment: You mention 'crashing' in the title but not the body.  Why aren't you verifying that `window` & `renderer` are non-`nullptr` before attempting to use them?

Comment: I'm getting a window with a red canvas for 3 seconds, and then the application closes. There's no crash and neither AddressSanitizer nor UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer reports anything.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you, I thought there was something wrong. I just put the code into a different project and did all of the necessary linking and it ended up working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the 3 seconds delay, the program progresses to the following lines:

```
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
```

which close the window and terminate the program. To keep the window open until the user manually closes it, you need to add a loop to handle events and keep the application running:

```
#include <SDL.h>

#ifdef main
#undef main
#endif

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLwindow", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    // Event loop
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```